# Stopping time and open/closed sets

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

*Question about Karatzas & Shreve - Brownian motion and stochastic calculus : Problem 2.7 chapter 1 (page 7 and solution page 39)*

Let $X$ a continuous process, $\Gamma$ a closed set and we have :

- $\Gamma_n=\{x\in\mathbb R^d; \rho(x,\Gamma) < 1/n\}$ with $\rho(x,\Gamma) = \inf\{\|x-y\|; y\in\Gamma\}$
- $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ the reaching time of $\Gamma_n$ (it is an optional time)
- $T:=\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$
- $H_{\Gamma} :=\inf \{t\geq 0; X_t \in \Gamma\}$ an hitting time.

The question of the exercise is to show that $H_{\Gamma}$, is a stopping time.

All the argumention of Karatzas et al. is to show that : $H_{\Gamma} = T$ (*).

**My problem:**

Nevertheless, I do not understand the conclusion written after having shown (*) : $\{H\leq t\}=\cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ (copied/pasted)

If I split up it, thanks to (*) : $\{H\leq t\} = \{T\leq t\}= \{T < t\} \cup \{T = t\}= \cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ (**)

However something disturb me, I can say : $\{T < t\} = \cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$

But we cannot say : $\{T = t\} \subseteq \cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ because it means that $\{T = t\} \subseteq \{T_\infty=T<t\}$ ?

Does my split (**) is correct ?
$$
%"{\cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\} = \{T_n<t\}\cap\{T_n<t\}\cap...\cap\{T_\infty=T<t\}}"
$$

Comment: The faulty step is when you state that $\{T < t\} = \bigcap\limits^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$, a priori one has $\{T < t\} \subseteq \bigcap\limits^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ and it happens that in fact $\{T \leqslant t\} = \bigcap\limits^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$.

Comment: I said $\{T < t\} = \cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ because I have thought that the hypothesis _$X$ is a continous process_ is enough to state that

Comment: It is not: the deterministic equivalent is to believe that if $T_n=1-\frac1n$ then $T_n<1$ for every $n$ hence $T=\lim T_n$ is such that $T<1$.

Comment: But one thing disturb me : $\cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}\cap\{\lim T_n = t\}$ is not equal to the null set ?

Comment: Not necessarily (it will often be the null set, but for an entirely different reason, which is that $(T=t)$ has probability zero in many situations anyway). Did you test this last idea of yours in the simple setting I proposed in my previous comment? What did it yield?

Comment: But what I do not understand is : Inside this set $\cap^\infty_{n=1}\{T_n<t\}$ you have this one "$\{T_{\infty}<t\}$", no ?

Comment: Yes, if $T<t$ then $T_n<t$ for every $n$ (since $T_n\leqslant T$ by definition). But even if $T_n<t$ for every $n$, $T<t$ is not guaranteed, only $T\leqslant t$ is.

Answer (score 1):

The key to the equality $\{H\le t\}=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\{T_n<t\}$, which is asserted by Karatzas & Shreve for $t>0$, is the fact that $\{T_n\}$ approximates $H$ strictly from below on $\{H>0\}$, as detailed in the "dichotomy" listed in their solution to the problem. (Plus the fact that $\{H=0\}=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\{T_n=0\}$.)

Comment: But the demonstration show mainly $H=T$ by doing firstly $T<H$ (first part with the dichotomy) then $H\leq T$ (2nd part). Probably I am wrong (_tell me if it is the case_) but it is **only** in order to write $\{H<t\}=\{T<t\}(=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\{T_n<t\})$

Comment: The goal is to show that $H$ is a stopping time; namely that $\{H\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t$. To this end the event $\{H<t\}$ is not especially relevant. It is noted that each $T_n$ is optional (so that $\{T_n<t\}\in\mathcal F_t$), which together with the representation $\{H\le t\}=\cap_n\{T_n<t\}$ ($t>0$) shows that $\{H\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ if $t>0$. That $\{H\le 0\}\in\mathcal F_0$ is trivial.

Comment: I have already understood that ultimately we need to prove that $H$ is a stopping time, but my question still remain.